# HTML and Javascript: how to set image as button?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have the following button and JS code:

```
<button type="button" id="play-pause" ><img id = "playbtn" src="img/icons/play.png"></button>
 playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

              if (video.paused == true) {
                // Play the video
                video.play();

                // Update the button text to 'Pause'
                 document.getElementById("playbtn").src = "img/icons/pause.png";
              } else {
                // Pause the video
                video.pause();

                // Update the button text to 'Play'
                document.getElementById("playbtn").src = "img/icons/play.png";
              }
            });
```

When i click my button it changes the button to a play icon image and when i click it again it changes it to a pause icon button. This works fine but it still displays the default button background. I want it to be just an image. It currently gives my a button GUI with an image in it. Thats not what I want, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset default `<button>` styles via CSS. This [link](http://codepen.io/terkel/pen/dvejH) might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not changing the value of **video.paused**

```
 playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

          if (video.paused == true) {
            video.paused = false;
            // Play the video
            video.play();

            // Update the button text to 'Pause'
             document.getElementById("playbtn").src = "img/icons/pause.png";
          } else {
            video.paused = true;
            // Pause the video
            video.pause();

            // Update the button text to 'Play'
            document.getElementById("playbtn").src = "img/icons/play.png";
          }
        });
```